# Looking up address of last not matiching value

Tags: excel, lookup

I like to know what the timestamp was of the last OUT for every IN (yellow highlight) , but I cannot seem to figure it out.

I have the following list of values:

### [image: Excel print screen]

The output should look something like that:

```
IN    2019-03-04 09:47:56.5855908 +01:00   2019-03-04 09:48:00.8269434 +01:00
OUT   2019-03-04 09:47:59.9238027 +01:00
OUT   2019-03-04 09:47:59.9258067 +01:00
OUT   2019-03-04 09:48:00.4588377 +01:00
OUT   2019-03-04 09:48:00.8028618 +01:00
OUT   2019-03-04 09:48:00.8269434 +01:00
IN    2018-09-07 10:10:21.8107528 +02:00   2018-09-07 10:11:08.5897285 +02:00
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Can you show what the output should look like?

Comment: I tried finding the next value bij uesing VLOOKUP and then trying to get the ADDRESS. BY using INDIRECT to get the value of the cell I actually wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OUTs you are interested in are those where the value of the IN/OUT column in that row is OUT but the value in the *next* row is not.

For example, assuming your IN/OUT column starts at A1, you could define conditional formatting for B1 with the following formula:

```
=AND(A1="OUT",A1<>A2)
```

to indicate the desired cells, and apply that formatting to the rest of the column.

We could extend that by putting the following in a new column to just show the desired timestamps:

```
=IF(AND(A1="OUT",A1<>A2),B1,"")
```

If you change the `""` at the end to `C2`, the desired timestamp will appear next to each IN; it will also appear next to each of the corresponding OUTS (which could be hidden with conditional formatting; or you could have a new column just showing the IN values, and "" for the OUTs).

Comment: Thanks! That was it. :D